# android make layout scrollable when the keyboard appears

Tags: android, xml, scrollview

I have a layout which is taking full screen height and contains 2 edittext when clicking on edittext softinputkeyboard appears which covers rest of my other view

I used
 **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"**
but it just shrinks my view .What i want is view should be scrollable when softinputkeyboard appears.

hears my xml

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/activity_sign_in"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:weightSum="10"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="4">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and if add scrollview directly views becomes bigger. or removes all empty space 
independent of weight i have given to layout.

Comment: where is the scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution

In Manifest file :

```
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`